# Are end-stage Alzheimer's patients still conscious?

Tags: neuroscience, consciousness

I asked the same question at Reddit [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/jfdml/are_endstage_alzheimers_patients_still_conscious/), but none of the responses were convincing.

So here's the thing: to the extent of what we know about consciousness, are end-stage Alzheimer's patients still conscious? I will use [Christof Koch's attempt to define consciousness](http://www.klab.caltech.edu/~koch/Elsevier-NCC.html), as explained below.

> What is the character of the NCC? Most popular has been the belief
>   that consciousness arises as an emergent property of a very large
>   collection of interacting neurons (for instance, Libet 1993). In this
>   view, it would be foolish to locate consciousness at the level of
>   individual neurons. An alternative hypothesis is that there are
>   special sets of ``consciousness" neurons distributed throughout cortex
>   and associated systems. **Such neurons represent the ultimate neuronal
>   correlate of consciousness, in the sense that the relevant activity of
>   an appropriate subset of them is both necessary and sufficient to give
>   rise to an appropriate conscious experience or percept (Crick and Koch
>   1998).** Generating the appropriate activity in these neurons, for
>   instance by suitable electrical stimulation during open skull surgery,
>   would give rise to the specific percept.

So do end-stage Alzheimer's patients lose these types of "neurons"?